# ListView in a Popup WIndow

Tags: android, listview, onclick, popupwindow

I've searched around for a few hours now and haven't been able to find any thing that fixes my issue.  I have an application where I use a pop-up window.  Within that popup Window I want to display a list of contacts on my phone, this part I have working.  I created an a adapter that extends ArrayAdapter and I have it populating the list with the phones contacts.

But now I want to interact with these contacts, ie. click on one and show the contact's information to the user.  I add an OnItemClickListener() to the list but it never gets called.  I've tried making the cells not focusable, I've tried adding onClickListeners to each Item, but this doesn't give highlights to the cells.  I am stuck.

Below is the code I use to setup the ListView and add the onItemClick listener to the list view.

```
ListView contactList = (ListView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);
  ContactsProcessing processContacts = new ContactsProcessing();
  contactList.setAdapter(processContacts.getListAdapter());
  contactList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
  contactList.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
  contactList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Toast toast = new Toast(MainActivity.this);
        toast.setText("Item Clicked");
        toast.show();
        m_ButtonFeedback.hapticFeedback();
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Item Clicked");


     }
  });
```

In the same pop-up window I also have an exit button.  It works the way I expect.

```
ImageButton exit = (ImageButton) contentView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_close_button);
  exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View _v) {
        window.dismiss();

     }
  });
```

Here is my cell's XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:id="@+id/contact_cell_root" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contact_cell_headerText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:textColor="#29abe2"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/contact_cell_header_divider" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#29abe2"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_cell_user_image"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/contact_default"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_cell_titleText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="John Smith"

            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp" 
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_cell_companyName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titleText"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Company Name"

            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_cell_imageView"    
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:focusable="false"
         />
</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:id="@+id/contact_cell_divider" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#e7e7e7"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is your PopupWindow coding in which you are adding your listview ? I have the issue in Adding ListView in PopupWindow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that Popup Windows are created not Focusable.  The easy fix is to tell the Popup Window to be focusable.

```
PopupWindow window;
window = new PopupWindow(context);
window.setFocusable(true);
```

Once focusable, all the components in the view are active.

Comment: When you do this you loose onKey events to the underlying Activity.  Which means you can't capture them and use them.

Comment: Thanks Scott , but Doesnt work , in my case ! for that i have created a custom adapter , and in getView() i have added , onCLickListener() in the view .

Answer (score 2):

Looks like my solution is one of those Scott already tried but in the case someone still looking for some kind of implementation I'm posting this here.

So I had the same problem, but in my case `setFocusble(false)` was required (and using `ListPopupWindow` was not a solution in my case as a lot of stuff in the project already used base `PopupWindow`'s functionality including extending).

If someone in the same situation there is a kind of workaround based on bug discusson [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414) (post #9)

The main idea is that `ListView`'s hierarchy is still receives touch events so we can manually trigger `onItemClick()`.

However this approach is not 100% identical to real `ListView`'s touch handling (like there is no glow of selection while tapping a row) this done pretty well for me for the moment.

If someone has more precise solution of this problem, please share.

So, here is complete `Adapter`'s code which can be used with `ListView` inside `PopupWindow` which is `setFocusable(false)`:

private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ListView mOwningListView;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> objects, ListView listView) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objects);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mOwningListView = listView;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.font_pick_row, null);
    }
    // this is the key point of workaround
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*
             *  as every row is still receiving their touches
             *  we can use this to manually trigger onItemClick
             *  since it doesn't firing in popupWindow.setFocusable(false)  
             */
            mOwningListView.getOnItemClickListener().onItemClick(mOwningListView, v, position, getItemId(position));

        }
    });
    //... other stuff
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: This is a great way around the focusable(false), I've just implemented this solution after having spent hours, fixing the behavior of my application, and now this actually makes things possible I had given up on. Thank you very much for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

An way to fix this is to make a dialog, and then use the setItems() command, if you look here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

scroll down to "Adding a list" and there is an example, here on each item you can define onClick()